# DATEDIFF Getting the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the previous month relative to the current date

> SELECT datediff(mm,-1,2-2-2011)

This query gives **67** which is a wrong value .. where i went wrong ?

Comment: Are you looking for `DATEADD` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use **DATEADD**

eg.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Isn't it `DATE_ADD()` by the way?

Answer (score 8):

This `2-2-2011` is not a valid date literal - you are subtracting 2 from 2 and then 2011 from the result - proper date literals are `'2-2-2011'` and `#2-2-2011#`. You can use `GETDATE()` to get the current date, instead of relying on a literal.

Nor should you be using `DATEDIFF` - it gives you the *difference* between dates.

You should be using `DATEADD` to calculate new dates.

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1, GETDATE())
```

This will get the date a month ago.

If you just want the *month*, you need to also use `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm, SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT datepart(mm, dateadd(mm,-1,'2011/1/1') )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the month before the current month, you want
`SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))`

If you want the date for a month before the current date, you want
`SELECT DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())`

BTW, `SELECT datediff(mm,-1,2-2-2011)` computes the number of months between day -1 and day -2011, which is 67 (2010 / 30). That's nowhere near what you seem to actually want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **DATEADD** - not `DATEDIFF`

`DATEDIFF` calculates the **difference** between two dates - it doesn't add day or months to an existing date....

Also, you need to put your dates into single quotes: use `'2-2-2011'` instead of simply `2-2-2011`.

And lastly: I would strongly recommend using the **ISO-8601** date format **YYYYMMDD** (here: `20110202`) - it will work regardless of the language and regional settings on your SQL Server - your date format will BREAK on many servers due to language settings.

Answer (score 1):

DATEDIFF calculates the difference between your stating and ending dates 
every date previous to the current date has a positive number and every date next to the current date has negative number, this works in geting your specific date weather it a day,month,year or hour to understand this better below is the syntax of datediff

```
DATEDIFF (your datetime type, your starting date,your ending date)
```

the function does `(your ending date)-(your starting date)`

in your case the below datediff will work just pefectly

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (month,[you_date_or_datetime_column],GETDATE()) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEADD try this code

**For previous month**

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

**For 7 day previous**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-7 days"));
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `date` LIKE '%$date%'
```

$date varibale get previous  date date